How to precompile and dump Lua binary with C closures?
Currently I have a Lua-driven system with C functions connected. When it is built from source, it is constructed as below:
// bind C functions to make them callable inside Lua code
lua_pushlightuserdata(lua, some_cxx_object);
lua_pushcclosure(lua, global_function_foo, 1);
lua_setglobal(lua, "foo");

lua_pushcclosure(lua, global_function_bar, 0);
lua_setglobal(lua, "bar");

...... many more bindings ......

// compile Lua source code
auto re = luaL_loadbufferx( guts->lua, source, source_len, nullptr, nullptr );
if (re != LUA_OK)
    raise_exceptions();

// use the prepared Lua system
......

Now I want to use precompiled binaries to improve system init speed. My question is: how does lua_dump work with those C closure globals? Specifically:

When I'm going to compile & dump, should I bind C functions before compile?
When I'm going to use the precompiled binary, do I need to bind C functions again, before loading the binary?



When I'm going to compile & dump, should I bind C functions before compile?

No, just like how you can run luac to compile a single lua script.

When I'm going to use the precompiled binary, do I need to bind C functions again, before loading the binary?

Yes, but not before loading, but before running, so the only difference is that you can save compilation time.

Also, luac can compile and combine multiple Lua scripts.
